# Strange CSS Issue on Android 4.0.3 Default Browser

Tags: android

I created a mobile website which has a content slider with overlay text and bulleted navigation + a fixed ad banner at bottom of the page. Overlay text and navigation buttons arr placed inside separate div elements and div elements css position is set as absolute. And the fixed ad banner at the page bottom is placed in another div its css position is set as fixed.

On Android 4.0.3 Default Browser I experiences a strange issue which is not there in any other browser or mobile platforms. Am using samsung Galaxy SII to test this.

Issue:
Whenever the fixed banner appears all the above absolutely positioned div elements are not visible. Why this happens?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look on this issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=31862
I had many problems with the stock browser too.

Comment: I can confirm as well that it happens on 4.0.3, and if you use Chrome with same android version - it works fine